# Extreme lag in the viewport directly after Startup

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I've just installed Blender on my new Surface Pro 7 
(Quad-core 10th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1035G4 Processor, Intel® Iris™ Plus Graphics, 8GB LPDDR4x RAM) and really can't get it to work properly. 
(Blender System Info: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10l_Wgz7lPkp2rcvESULWuxjG8vWTaaSI/view?usp=sharing)

Directly after startup, it is unusable, because whatever I do in the viewport is extremly laggy. The main issue is the viewport. Nonetheless the menu bars at the top ("File", "Edit",...) are lagging a little bit as well.

If I try to move the cube in the startup file, it seems like blender is overwhelmed (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SS50Ta1a-CLOd4xGaRvic3TBbBQwGDDd/view?usp=sharing).

I've already downloaded the newest experimental Version, same Problem, no Solution.

On my Old Laptop (Quad-core 8th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-8250U Processor, Geforce GTX 1050, 8GB LPDDR4x RAM) everything runs as smooth as butter.

Actually, I really cant imagine that the Surface is to weak for Blender, or is it?!?! I've been browsing for this topic a couple of hours but couldn't find something fitting, so I would be really glad if someone can help me :D

Comment: You may want to compare gpu ratings.  There are definitely web sites that do this ... https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php

Comment: Check your GPU drivers!

Comment: The CPU on the Surface is better, the GPU is a lot worse. Nonetheway, Blender suddenly started to work mostly correct, it works alrigth for me. Thanks!